# Put a value stored in a database as the height of a div

Tags: php, javascript, database

I'm trying to put a value stored in a database as the height of the div "levelbarotherteam". The Id "levelotherteam" is just here to look if the data are received. That's good for levelotherteam, it's displayed a value every second but it's not working for levelbarotherteam. In my database, I store a new data every second and I want to display it on the div "levelbarotherteam".

The database looks like that :

Table : level

Id (as second):        1   2   3   4   5

height (as height):   203 235 124 245 245

Html :

```
<div> other: <span id="levelotherteam"></span> </div>
<div id="levelbarotherteam" style=" width:100%;margin:auto;" ></div>
```

Script:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'recept.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {

        $('#levelotherteam').html(result);      
        $('#levelbarotherteam').css("height", (result)+ "px");      

        }
    });
    }, 1000);
```

PHP :

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("cheer") or die(mysql_error());

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT height FROM level") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
  $direct = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

 while($direct = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 $direct['height'];
 $cheer = $direct['height'];
    echo "$cheer";
    echo "<br />";
 } 

 ?>
```

CSS :

```
#levelbarteam{
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#faa040;
    opacity:0.5; 
    margin:auto;
    height:2px;
}

#levelbarotherteam{
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#49495d; 
    opacity:82%;
    margin:auto;
    height:2px;
    -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: height 0.2s ease-out;

}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Have you tried looking at the element with Firebug while it is changing (or while the code is supposed to be changing it)?  Is it possible that "result" has extra spaces around the height value?

Comment: The height stay at 2px as mentionned in the css. Maybe it's coming from the echo "<br/>"?

Comment: Well yes - that would result in the height being set to "215<br/>px" which would just be completely ignored by the browser.

Comment: But if I delete the <br/> the value looks like that : 50 50305 50305101 50305101132 etc.. and a div with that value...

Comment: You could always add the "<br>" in JavaScript.

Comment: Can't we use a .remove or something like that? I'm not sure of the efficiency of the <br/>. I think it will do the same thing as the br in the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo out that `<br>` from PHP.  Instead, add it in JavaScript:

```
    $('#levelotherteam').html(result + '<br>');      
    $('#levelbarotherteam').css("height", (result)+ "px");
```

Comment: levelotherteam is just here to show what happened between javascript and php. There is no effect between this div and the div "levelbarotherteam". With your example it will just displayed the value with the <br> in the div levelotherteam but the css of "levelbarotherteam" will not change (always put the sequence of numbers ones behind the others ). I don't know if I'm clear. Tell me if you don't understand!

Comment: I Just solved my problem with just a simple UPDATE in the php file. Just a small work with tables in my database! All the rest is good!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Echoing that `<br>` in your PHP script means that the response your Javascript code receives is actually `245<br>`. You then try to assign that directly to a css property, which translates to this:

```
      $('#levelbarotherteam').css("height", "245<br>px");
```

That's invalid CSS, just as doing:

```
<style>
   .something { height: 245<br>px; }
</style>
```

Don't transmit the `<br>` from PHP, apply it directly in your Javascript instead.